# Authentication in Angular 2, handling the observables

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular, angular2-routing

I just started with a Angular 2 project and am trying to get authentication up and running. Inspired by [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/authentication-in-angular-2-958052c64492#.t7gwxklkv) I decided to do the following:

- Create a custom RouterOutlet class (extending it) to handle the authentication logic whenever a url is called.

I succeeded in this custom class, but am still not sure how to check if a user is authenticated. My situation is as follows, I need to query a get call to a external API, for my development proces it is as follows:

```
getAdmin() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/is_admin.json', options)
        .map(res => res)
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

This API call returns true or false. I was wondering what would be the best option to use this information? Should I for example call the following function each time a URL should be checked?:

```
isAdmin() {
    this.getAdmin().subscribe(
        data => this.authenticationResult = data,
        error => console.log("Error: ", error),
        () => return JSON.parse(this.authenticationResult._data);
}
```

I can't get this up and running because my observable is undefined when using the function I gave as example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is that your method is asynchronous so you need to be careful the way and when you use it.

If you want to use within the `activate` method of your custom `RouterOutlet`, you need to leverage observables and reactive programming.

I don't know exactly the way you want to check admin roles:

```
activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
  return this.userService.getAdmin().flatMap((isAdmin) => {
    if (this.userService.isLoggIn()) {
      if (this._canActivate(instruction.urlPath, isAdmin) {
        return Observable.fromPromise(super.activate(instruction));
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['Forbidden']);
        return Observable.throw('Forbidden');
      }
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['Login']);
      return Observable.throw('Not authenticated');
    }
  }).toPromise();
}

_canActivate(url, admin) {
  return this.publicRoutes.indexOf(url) !== -1
    || this.userService.isLoggedIn();
}
```

In order to optimize the request, you could lazily (and only once) call the request to check if the user is admin or not:

```
isAdmin:boolean;

getAdmin() {
  if (this.isAdmin) {
    return Observable.of(this.isAdmin);
  } else {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/is_admin.json', options)
      .map(res => res)
      .catch(this.handleError);
   }
}
```

Another approach will be also to load this hint when authenticating the user. This way, the implementation of the `activate` method would be simplier:

```
activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
  if (this.userService.isLoggIn()) {
    if (this.userService.isAdmin()) {
      return super.activate(instruction);
    } else if (this._canActivate(instruction.urlPath, isAdmin) {
      return super.activate(instruction);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['Forbidden']);
    }
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['Login']);
  }
}

_canActivate(url, admin) {
  return this.publicRoutes.indexOf(url) !== -1
    || this.userService.isLoggedIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider to call getAdmin() somehow as first Step of your app,  store  the result in a SessionService object which you move around using Dependency Injection. This way any time you need to check the result of getAdmin you can ask the SessionService instance.
I hope this helps