# Importing custom service in extended RouterOutlet in Angular 2 for authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am trying to set up authentication in Angular 2, with the help from [the following article](https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/authentication-in-angular-2-958052c64492#.t7gwxklkv) (and from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062171/authentication-in-angular-2-handling-the-observables) on SO) I managed to create my own extended RouterOutlet:

```
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    publicRoutes: any;
    private parentRouter: Router;
    private loginService: LoginService;

    constructor(_viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
        _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string,
        private loginService: LoginService) {
        super(_viewContainerRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

        this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
        this.publicRoutes = {
            'login': true
        };
    }

    _canActivate(url: string, admin: boolean) {
        => Checks with my loginService if user is authenticated
    }


    activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
            if (this._canActivate(url, isAdmin)) {
                => Go to desired URL
            } else {
                => Go to login page
            }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that my typescript generates the following error:

> "Duplicate identifier 'loginService'"

My code does function as expected, I just don't like the typescript errors when parsing typescript to javascript. If I rename the second loginService however, my code does break and I can find a

> TypeError: this.loginService is undefined

In my console. I was wondering if anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: You have a class property `loginService` and a constructor parameter `loginService2`. Is this this the code that produces the error, or is this only when you name the constructor parameter the same as the property?

Comment: My bad, it's actually giving the error when I call them both loginService (but the code works). When I call it loginService2 it breaks.

Comment: I think I got it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `loginService` twice in your class

```
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    publicRoutes: any;
    private parentRouter: Router;
    // private loginService: LoginService; // <== remove this
```

and name the parameter `loginService` instead of `loginService2`

```
constructor(_viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
    _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string,
    private loginService: LoginService) {
    super(_viewContainerRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);
```

A `private` or `public` modifier on a constructor parameter already declares a class property with this name. No need to declare the property explicitely again.

Comment: Damn, quite easy when you explain it like this. Still quite hard to find for a beginner. Thanks!